# How to stop Replicaset from restarting?

Tags: kubernetes, replicaset, kubectl

I started a test if my kubernetes installation is running well, with:

```
$ kubectl run -it hello --image=busybox -- sh
```

However it didn't work. Now I want to just clean up everything before I figure out how to continue. But if I `delete`the pod it gets restarted, I suppose by a corresponding replicaset. But this gets restarted as well if I `delete it`. What can I do now to clean up whatever `kubectl run` did?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The run command creates a deployment which controls the replicaset please run the following commands to verify and solve:

```
kubectl get deployments

kubectl delete deployment hello
```