# How to kill pods on Kubernetes local setup

Tags: kubernetes

I am starting exploring runnign docker containers with Kubernetes. I did the following

```
1. docker run etcd
2. docker run master
3. docker run service proxy
4. kubectl run web --image=nginx
```

To cleanup the state, I first stopped all the containers and cleared the downloaded images. However I still see pods running.

```
$ kubectl get pods 
NAME                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
web-3476088249-w66jr   1/1       Running   0          16m
```

How can I remove this?

Comment: This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138636/how-do-i-delete-orphan-kubernetes-pods?rq=1)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop Replicaset from restarting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230541/how-to-stop-replicaset-from-restarting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Delete Orphan Kubernetes Pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138636/how-do-i-delete-orphan-kubernetes-pods)

Answer (score 87):

To delete the pod:

```
kubectl delete pods web-3476088249-w66jr
```

If this pod is started via some replicaSet or deployment or anything that is creating replicas then find that and delete that first.

```
kubectl get all
```

This will list all the resources that have been created in your k8s cluster. To get information with respect to resources created in your namespace `kubectl get all --namespace=<your_namespace>`

To get info about the resource that is controlling this pod, you can do

```
kubectl describe  web-3476088249-w66jr
```

There will be a field "Controlled By", or some owner field using which you can identify which resource created it.

Comment: @Madhusoodan k8s recreates the pod only if it is being controlled by some controller like replica set, deployment, etc. You should describe the pod to find out who is controlling that pod and delete that controller first and then delete the pod. This way pod will be killed permanently.

Comment: had to add -n <namespace> to the end to get this to work, without it it didn't work for me because my pod was not in the default namespace (no error message either)

Comment: shouldn't be `kubectl describe pod web-3476088249-w66jr` instead?

Answer (score 21):

When you do `kubectl run ...`, that's a deployment you create, not a pod directly. You can check this with `kubectl get deploy`. If you want to delete the pod, you need to delete the deployment with `kubectl delete deploy DEPLOYMENT`.

I would recommend you to create a namespace for testing when doing this kind of things. You just do `kubectl create ns test`, then you do all your tests in this namespace (by adding `-n test`). Once you have finished, you just do `kubectl delete ns test`, and you are done.

Answer (score 12):

If you defined your object as `Pod` then

```
kubectl delete pod <--all | pod name>
```

will remove all of the generated `Pod`. But, If wrapped your `Pod` to `Deployment` object then running the command above only will trigger a re-creation of them.

In that case, you need to run

```
kubectl delete deployment <--all | deployment name>
```

That will also remove the `Service` object that is related to the deleted `Deployment`

Comment: I deleted the deployment, but it still left the associated services running.

Answer (score 0):

You would do `kubectl -n NAME_SPACE delete pods POD_NAME`