# Kubernetes keeps spawning Pods after deletion

Tags: kubernetes

The following is the file used to create the Deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kloud-php7
  namespace: kloud-hosting
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kloud-php7
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kloud-php7
        image: 192.168.1.1:5000/kloud-php7
      - name: kloud-nginx
        image: 192.168.1.1:5000/kloud-nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

The Deployment and the Pod worked fine, but after deleting the Deployment and a generated ReplicaSet, the I cannot delete the spawn Pods permanently. New Pods will be created if old ones are deleted.

The kubernetes cluster is created with kargo, containing 4 nodes running CentOS 7.3, kubernetes version 1.5.6

Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop Replicaset from restarting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230541/how-to-stop-replicaset-from-restarting)

Answer (score 7):

This is working as intended. The Deployment creates (and recreates) a ReplicaSet and the ReplicaSet creates (and recreates!) Pods. You need to delete the Deployment, not the Pods or the ReplicaSet:

```
kubectl delete deploy -n kloud-hosting kloud-php7
```

Comment: I already deleted the deployment. `kubectl get deployment -n kloud-hosting` showing nothing. But the Pods are left running

Comment: @user416983 try deleting the replicaset.

Comment: Interesting. Could you please execute `kubectl get --all-namespaces pod,rc,rs,deploy`

Answer (score 1):

This is Because the replication set always enables to recreate the pods as mentioned in the deployment file(suppose say 3 ..kube always make sure that 3 pods up and running)

so here we need to delete replication set first to get rid of pods.

```
kubectl get rs
```

and delete the replication set .this will in turn deletes the pods

Answer (score 1):

It could be the deamonsets need to be deleted.

For example:

```
$ kubectl get DaemonSets
NAME                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY         UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
elasticsearch-operator-sysctl   5         5         5         5            5           <none>          6d

$ kubectl delete daemonsets elasticsearch-operator-sysctl
```

Now running `get pods` should not list `elasticsearch*` pods.